# Gnuplot: oscilloscope-like line style?

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible in Gnuplot to emulate the drawing style of an analogue oscilloscope, meaning thinner+dimmisher lines on larger amplitudes, like this:?

[image: my personal oscilloscope-like drawing test]

Comment: Question answered?

Answer (score 5):

The effect you see in the oscilloscope trace is not due to amplitude, it is due to the rate of change as the trace is drawn.  If you know that rate of change and can feed it to gnuplot as a third column of values, then you could use it to modulate the line color as it is drawn:

```
  plot 'data' using 1:2:3 with lines linecolor palette z
```

I don't know what color palette would work best for your purpose, but here is an approximation using a function with an obvious, known, derivative.

```
  set palette gray
  set samples 1000
  plot '+' using ($1):(sin($1)):(abs(cos($1))) with lines linecolor palette
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For thickness variations, you could shift the curve slightly up and down, and fill the area between them.

```
f(x) = sin(2*x) * sin(30*x)
dy = 0.02
plot '+' u 1:(f(x)+dy):(f(x)-dy) w filledcurves ls 1 notitle
```

[image: Area filled between shifted curves]

This does not allow variable colour, but the visual effect is similar.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

As @Ethan already stated, the intensity is somehow proportional to the speed of movement, i.e. the derivative. If you have `sin(x)` as waveform, the derivative is `cos(x)`. But what if you have given data? Then you have to calculate the derivative numerically.
Furthermore, depending on the background the line should fade from white (minimal derivative) to fully transparent (maximum derivative), i.e. you should change the *transparency* with the derivative.

**Code:**

```
### oscilloscope "imitation"
reset session

set term wxt size 500,400 butt  # option butt, otherwise you will get overlap points
set size ratio 4./5
set samples 1000
set xrange[-5:5]

# create some test data
f(x) = 1.5*sin(15*x)*(cos(1.4*x)+1.5)
set table $Data
    plot '+' u 1:(f($1)) w table
unset table

set xtics axis 1 format ""
set mxtics 5
set grid xtics ls -1
set yrange[-4:4]
set ytics axis 1 format ""
set mytics 5
set grid ytics ls -1

ColorScreen = 0x28a7e0
set obj 1 rect from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 behind
set obj 1 fill solid 1.0 fc rgb ColorScreen

x0=y0=NaN
Derivative(x,y) = (dx=x-x0,x0=x,x-dx/2,dy=y-y0,y0=y,dy/dx)   # approx. derivative
# get min/max derivative
set table $Dummy
    plot n=0 $Data u (d=abs(Derivative($1,$2)),n=n+1,n<=2? (dmin=dmax=d) : \
                     (dmin>d ? dmin=d:dmin), (dmax<d?dmax=d:dmax)) w table
unset table

myColor(x,y) = (int((abs(Derivative(column(x),column(y)))-dmin)/(dmax-dmin)*0xff)<<24) +0xffffff

plot $Data u 1:2:(myColor(1,2)) w l lw 1.5 lc rgb var not
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]